# Find all vectors **v** such that the resultant is parallel to the **x-y** plane

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

Find all vectors **v** such that the resultant of $\langle2,3,0 \rangle$, $\langle0,6,1 \rangle$, $\langle2,0,-4 \rangle$ and **v** is parallel to the **x-y** plane.

For these vectors' resultant to be parallel to **x-y**  plane, we want

$\langle 2,3,0 \rangle $ +  $\langle0,6,1 \rangle$ + $\langle2, 0,-4 \rangle$ +
$\langle a,b,c \rangle $ = $\langle 4+a,9+b,-3+c \rangle$ parallel to **x-y** plane where **v** =
$\langle a,b,c \rangle $
which is possible only when **v** = $\langle a,b,3\rangle$ where $a,b\in R$

Is this correct?

Comment: I have posted this question because one of the solutions that I read online said that we want the $z$ component of the resultant to be a constant, which did not make sense to me as if the $z$ component is non-zero then the vector will either rise or fall hence won't be parallel to the $x-y$ plane

Comment: Consider the plane $z=1$, isn't it parallel to the $xy-$plane?

Comment: @AnuragA but none of the position vectors representing the points in that plane are parallel to the xy-plane, right... or am I missing something..

Comment: @AnuragA initial point is on origin

Comment: @Abhay where does it say that $\mathbf{v}$ is a position vector? Any vector when translated will remain the same vector.

Comment: @AnuragA again, if the $z$ component is non zero, the vector will still rise or fall, right?

Comment: What is a **resultant** of $4$ vectors?

Comment: @Berci their sum